# Why does scipy's interp2d return a 2D array instead of an 1D list?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate values on a 2D field that looks e.g. like this:

[image: Example of 2D field]

where the inner field represents a value of `1`.

If I use an interp2d interpolator like this:

```
# x: 1D list of x values, length n
# y: 1D list of y values, length m
# z: 2D array of z values, dimensions nxm
interpolator = interpolate.interp2d(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

Now when I call the interpolator with `interpolator([0.2, 0.4, 0.6], [0, 0, 0])` I would expect an 1D list of length 3 filled with ones. However I get a 3x3 array filled with ones. In the [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) only the first row of the results is actually used (`z[0, :]`). But what do the other rows of the result represent then?

Comment: [`interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) is actually [documented to behave that way](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html).  Note that `interp2d` has issues; see, for example, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16396.  Consider using [`RegularGridInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've specified: `z = f(x,y)` is of dimensions `n*m`. So, `interpolator([0.2, 0.4, 0.6], [0, 0, 0])` returning a 3x3 array makes sense.

In the Scipy example, they are plotting only the first row. Dimensionally,

`x, y, xnew, ynew` -> 1D

`z, xx, yy, znew` -> 2D

Comment: So is the interpolator returning every combination of my values in [0.2, 0.4, 0.6] and [0, 0, 0]? How could I use it to treat the values as pairs (i.e. `[(0.2, 0), (0.4, 0), (0.6, 0)]`) instead of the current behavior?

Comment: Yes, this is because you created the `interpolator` with `z.sahpe= (n, m)`.  To answer your question - I think you want the [diagonal of your matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The diagonal should be the correct result. Thanks!